# Showing equivalence of the hyperbolic function

Tags: integration

I've been thinking about this problem for about 30 minutes now and still I don't have a clue on what I'd do next. I have this equation and I aim to show equivalence (proof) between

$$\int\operatorname{csch}{(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u=\ln{\left(\tanh{\frac{u}{2}}\right)}+c.$$

If I made a move on the right hand side and placed $\tanh{\frac{u}{2}}$ with $\frac{\cosh{x}-1}{\sinh{x}}$, what can I do next? Any help or guide on answering this question is very much appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you tried differentiating the RHS?

Comment: I haven't. Is that the first step? Sorry, I'm not really good in Math. (Plus I was honestly absent when the topic of hyperbolic functions and the natural logarithm was discussed so you may take it as I have no idea at all on how to start) Any help on how to start proving this or even giving me a link so that I could study it up will do. Thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The main identity to know about hyperbolic functions is the hyperbolic-Pythagorean theorem (just as how the classical Pythagorean theorem is the most important relation for trig functions):

$$1=\cosh^2{(\phi)}-\sinh^2{(\phi)}.$$

Now, using the definition of the function $\operatorname{csch}{(z)}$ and a little algebra, we have:

$$\begin{align}
\int\operatorname{csch}{(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u
&=\int\frac{1}{\sinh{(u)}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\frac{1}{\sinh{(u)}}\cdot\frac{\sinh{(u)}}{\sinh{(u)}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\frac{\sinh{(u)}}{\sinh^2{(u)}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\frac{\sinh{(u)}}{\cosh^2{(u)}-1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align}$$

where in the last line we've substituted $x=\cosh{(u)}$, $dx=\sinh{(u)}\,du$.

---

**Hint #2:** The last integral can be broken down into elementary integrals via partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2(x-1)}-\frac{1}{2(x+1)},\\
\begin{align}~~~~~~~~~~~~~\implies\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2-1}&=\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-1}-\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x+1}\\
&=\frac12\ln{(x-1)}-\frac12\ln{(x+1)}+\color{grey}{\text{constant}}\\
&=\frac12\ln{\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)}+\color{grey}{\text{constant}}.
\end{align}$$

Hence, after back-substituting $x=\cosh{(u)}$,

$$\int\operatorname{csch}{(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac12\ln{\left(\frac{\cosh{(u)}-1}{\cosh{(u)}+1}\right)}+\color{grey}{\text{constant}}.$$

This solves the integral. The last step of the problem asks us to show that $\ln{\left(\tanh{\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)}\right)}$ is also an anti-derivative of $\operatorname{csch}{(u)}$, which is just a matter of algebra.

---

**Edit**

The partial fraction decomposition is found through a purely algebraic process (and has nothing to do with differentiation). Start by writing the rational function as a linear combination of its linear factors:

$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x+1}.$$

Multiplying by $(x-1)(x+1)$, we have:

$$1=A(x+1)+B(x-1).$$

To find the values of $A$ and $B$, first set $x=1$, and the equation reduces to $1=2A$. Similarly, by setting $x=-1$, we find $1=-2B$.

Comment: This has been most useful! If you won't mind, I may have to ask some questions on how you arrived at a particular step. I'll do this on my own first. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it took me long. Thank you for your availability. :) May I ask how did you arrive at this point? 1/x^2−1=1/2(x−1)−1/2(x+1). Where did you get 2? Is it by differentiation? Quotient rule perhaps? (but I think it's not the case)

Comment: @Silver It's from a procedure called [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). See my edit.

Comment: Thank you! (reallyyy) I didn't know about this process. Last question (and really sorry for bothering you) how will I know when I'd use this?

Comment: @Silver No bother at all! As for why you didn't know about the partial fraction decomp process, it's entirely possible your calculus class hasn't covered it yet, or perhaps it won't cover it at all if your course is at a very elementary level.

Comment: @Silver And as to your question of how you'll know when to use partial fractions, that's easy: whenever you need to integrate a complicated rational function. A rational function is a fraction whose numerator and denominator are polynomials. And FYI, WolframAlpha can do the decomposition [for you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions&lk=4&num=2).

Comment: Oh no. Now I don't even know where to start reviewing. It feels like I haven't learned anything at all. Anyway, thanks again and this will be my reallyyy last question: How come at the third step of the hint#2, there suddenly appeared a ln? Any rules on that one?

Comment: @Silver You mean the step that goes from $\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-1}-\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x+1}$ to $\frac12\ln{(x-1)}-\frac12\ln{(x+1)}+\color{grey}{\text{constant}}$? Well, "ln" terms are simply a result of integration. Do you know how to do the integral $\int\frac{dx}{x+a}$?

Comment: What I remember about integration is x^n+1/n+1 + constant (?) Why does it feel like I'm sooo doomed. Hahaha. I really need some studying to do. I'll get back to you on that one. :(( (because I honestly think I don't know how to do the integral of ∫dx/x+a) I really might ask for your help on times where I get confused... if that would be okay with you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\text{csch }x=\dfrac1{\sinh x}$ and $\sinh x=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}2$ . Then let $t=e^x$. The desired result soon follows.

Comment: I'll do this process too. Thank you so much! By the way, our teacher gave us formulas like that but have not actually explained where it came from (the e^x... thing) Is it really 'given'? Like an axiom or something?

Comment: @Silver Think about the hyperbola $y=\frac{1}{x}$. The area under the curve is computed from its integral $\log{x}$, whose inverse function is $e^x$. In such a way you can construct the hyperbolic functions from the geometry of hyperbolas in virtually complete analogy to the construction of the trigonometric functions from circles.

Comment: @Silver And as a footnote, there is a very, *very* deep connection between exponential functions and trigonometric functions. If you're curious, check out the [Euler's Formulua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). If you've never encountered this formula before, you might be genuinely shocked by it!

Comment: @Silver: The connection between circles and hyperbolas (and thus between trigonometric and hyperbolic functions) is related to the fact that their equations are of the form $x^2\pm y^2=r^2$.